# use tilde ~ in file names with PHP

Tags: php

I'd like to specify a path relative to `$HOME` directory of a user. For example:

```
$path = "~/deep/down/in/folder.zip";
$size = filesize($versionPath)
```

returns an error

```
filesize(): stat failed for ~/deep/down/in/folder.zip
```

If I use absolute path instead

```
$path = "/home/notapacherootfolder/deep/down/in/folder.zip";
$size = filesize($path);
```

it work as expected. Is it possible to use `~` in file names with PHP?

Comment: there is no meaning for `~` when used in file path in PHP, usually `__FILE__` and [realpath](https://www.php.net/realpath) are used for files paths.

Comment: As far as I know Linux shells replace `~` with current user's home directory, just like they replace `*`. I don't think there's a similar feature in PHP, let alone in web environment (not clear if that's the case).

Comment: You could try `./` instead ( of `~/` ) if you want relative path

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet Working directory and home directory do not necessarily match.

Comment: To get user home you can use [getenv](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) like so `getenv("HOME")`,